# Super-performatic comparison

Tags: python, performance

I have a python code which recovers information from an HTTP API using the `requests` module. This code is run over and over again with an interval of few milliseconds between each call.

The HTTP API which I'm calling can send me 3 different responses, which can be:

- text `'EMPTYFRAME'` with HTTP status `200`
- text `'CAMERAUNAVAILABLE'` with HTTP status `200`
- JPEG image with HTTP status `200`

This is part of the code which handles this situation:

```
   try:
        r = requests.get(url,
            auth=(username, pwd),
            params={
                  'camera': camera_id,
                  'ds': int((datetime.now() - datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds())
            }
        )

        if r.text == 'CAMERAUNAVAILABLE':
            raise CameraManager.CameraUnavailableException()
        elif r.text == 'EMPTYFRAME':
            raise CameraManager.EmptyFrameException()
        else:
            return r.content
    except ConnectionError:
        # handles the error - not important here
```

The critical part is the `if`/`elif`/`else` section, this comparison is taking *way too long* to complete and if I completely remove and simply replace it by `return r.content`, I have the performance I wish to, but checking for these other two responses other than the image is important for the application flow.

I also tried like:

```
        if len(r.text) == len('CAMERAUNAVAILABLE'):
            raise CameraManager.CameraUnavailableException()
        elif len(r.text) == len('EMPTYFRAME'):
            raise CameraManager.EmptyFrameException()
        else:
            return r.content
```

And:

```
        if r.text[:17] == 'CAMERAUNAVAILABLE':
            raise CameraManager.CameraUnavailableException()
        elif r.text[:10] == 'EMPTYFRAME':
            raise CameraManager.EmptyFrameException()
        else:
            return r.content
```

Which made it faster but still not as fast as I think this can get.

So is there a way to optimize this comparison?

**EDIT**

With the accepted answer, the final code is like this:

```
        if r.headers['content-type'] == 'image/jpeg':
            return r.content
        elif len(r.text) == len('CAMERAUNAVAILABLE'):
            raise CameraManager.CameraUnavailableException()
        elif len(r.text) == len('EMPTYFRAME'):
            raise CameraManager.EmptyFrameException()
```

Checking the response's `Content-Type` provided a *much faster* way to assure an image was received.

Comment: It would be nice if you showed your benchmarking results and the specifications of your computer.

Comment: Does the response include a `Content-Type` header? This should be set to `text/plain` or `image/jpeg`. Checking it should be much faster than reading the whole `r.text`.

Comment: @райтфолд There are no benchmarking. Basically this being repeatedly called by another page from a loop in JavaScript which draws the image to a `canvas` to simulate a live video. I can easily see the performance difference by looking at this video rendered on the page.

Comment: @Tichodroma indeed, comparing the header's `Content-Type` increased the performance as I needed, thanks for the idea! If you'll write an answer with that, I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @BrunoFinger answer added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the whole `r.text` (which may contain the JPEG bytes) is probably slow.

You could compare the `Content-Type` header the server should set:

```
ct = r.headers['content-type']
if ct == "text/plain":
    # check for CAMERAUNAVAILABLE or EMPTYFRAME
else:
    # this is a JPEG
```

Comment: The comparison should only inspect at most `len('CAMERAUNAVAILABLE')` bytes unless Whython is really dumb.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit  What is Whython? If you read my answer you will notice, that I don't compare the *body* but a *header* of the response. The length of a header will be small enough to compare it completely.

Comment: It is another name for Python. And if you read my comment you will notice, that I am responding to your claim _"comparing the whole `r.text` (which may contain the JPEG bytes) is probably slow"_.